# Why is my simple SQL statement taking so long to execute and how do i go about finding the issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple SQL query:

```
select o.Visit_ID
from Datamart.dbo.ww_Orders o
inner join Datamart.dbo.ww_Order_Details on o.Visit_ID = ww_Order_Details.Visit_ID
where o.runstamp = '20160422'
```

this query takes < 0 seconds to return 11173 rows

When I add the GROUP BY statement:

```
select o.Visit_ID
from Datamart.dbo.ww_Orders o
inner join Datamart.dbo.ww_Order_Details on o.Visit_ID = ww_Order_Details.Visit_ID
where o.runstamp = '20160422'
group by o.Visit_ID
```

the server takes 6min 30 sec to retrieve the 3047 rows.

I would expect the GROUP BY query to take not that much longer than the original. How do I go about finding what the issues are? thanks

---

here are the table definitions:

Orders:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ww_Orders](
    [Visit_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Member_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Membership_no] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Member_Card_Num_Orig] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [SCV_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Meeting_No] [int] NULL,
    [Location_Name] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [Leader_No] [int] NULL,
    [CashAmt] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [EFTAmt] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [VouchAmt] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Meet_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [runstamp] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ww_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Visit_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Order Details:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ww_Order_Details](
    [ord_det_pk] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Visit_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Item_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Item_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
    [Amt] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Category_Code] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ww_Order_Details] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ord_det_pk] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ww_Order_Details]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ww_Order_Details_ww_Orders] FOREIGN KEY([Visit_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ww_Orders] ([Visit_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ww_Order_Details] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ww_Order_Details_ww_Orders]
GO
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions? (Do you mean SELECT DISTINCT?)

Comment: Can you add table definitions, and indexes, to the question?

Comment: @jarlh - good point.. I guess out of habit. Im a big user of group by and at times forget I could just use distinct...

Comment: @jarlh - im also an absolute noob at database development so there are no indexes on these tables. could that be an issue? there are 2 mil records in the orders details table.

Comment: You have two basic diagnostic tools: explain plan and query tracing. If you use SQL Server Management Studio they both show up as toolbar icons.

Comment: can you please post statistics copy somewhere

Comment: And execution plan

Comment: Without much details people can guess only. in your situation it seems like stale statistics for current data distribution.

Comment: If you compare query plans between the fast and slow queries you'll probably see that the group by one requires a sort which is an expensive operations. (Distinct is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add an index onto ww_Order_Details Visit_ID, probably make it the clustered index and drop the index on ord_det_pk.  Also it might make more sense as an exists?

```
select o.Visit_ID
from Datamart.dbo.ww_Orders o
where exists (select 0 from Datamart.dbo.ww_Order_Details where o.Visit_ID = ww_Order_Details.Visit_ID)
and o.runstamp = '20160422'
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, changing the index to Visit_ID worked perfectly. Completes query in under 1 second :). I think I need to do some research on indexes :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to use a common table expression in cases like these, when a part of the query is really fast but an addition of a simple operation makes it really slow, usually it helps.
Try:

```
WITH CTE AS (
select o.Visit_ID
from Datamart.dbo.ww_Orders o
inner join Datamart.dbo.ww_Order_Details od on o.Visit_ID = od.Visit_ID
where o.runstamp = '20160422'
)
SELECT Visit_ID FROM CTE
group by Visit_ID
```

If this helps you can try to compare execution plans for your original query and this version to see whats going on

Comment: Thanks Alex, because I created the new index based on Mike's answer I didn't get to try your solution.. I guess using CTE is a bit like using #temp tables which I use now when I have these types of issues and I want to reuse query results. I will keep this method in mind for next time.